# Match two Python lists with regular expressions, and create dictionary output

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have the following two lists:

`input = ['MAPLEWOOD AVE', 'LYNNDALE ', 'SUGAR DR']`

`ref = ['LYNNDALE (?:RD)?', 'HOMAN (?:AVE)?', 'MAPLEWOOD (?:AVE)?', 'LYNNDALE (?:LN)?']`

I would like to look for all matches for each element within `input` with `ref`. The output would be a dictionary with each key being an `input` element, and each value being a `ref` element matched to the corresponding `input` element, like the following:

`{'MAPLEWOOD AVE' : 'MAPLEWOOD AVE', 'LYNNDALE ' : 'LYNNDALE RD', 'LYNNDALE LN', 'SUGAR DR':}`

The following allows me to iterate over `input` in search of a `findall` match within `ref` (which contains embedded regex groupings). However, I cannot retrieve the corresponding match element(s) from `ref` as values alongside each input element:

```
combined = "(" + ")|(".join(ref) + ")"

l = []

for i in input:
    if re.findall(combined,i):
         l.append(i)
...
MAPLEWOOD AVE
LYNNDALE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
import re

input = ['MAPLEWOOD AVE', 'LYNNDALE ', 'SUGAR DR']
ref = ['LYNNDALE (?:RD)?', 'HOMAN (?:AVE)?', 'MAPLEWOOD (?:AVE)?', 'LYNNDALE (?:LN)?']
output = dict([ (i, [ r for r in ref if re.match(r, i) ]) for i in input ])
```

Or if you're using Python 3:

```
output = { i : [ r for r in ref if re.match(r, i) ] for i in input }
```

Also you could compile your regexs to speed them up a little:

```
ref_re = [ re.compile(r) for r in ref ]
output = { i : [ r.pattern for r in ref_re if r.match(i) ] for i in input }
```

**UPD:**
Maybe you want to use matched part as values, not patterns:

```
output = { i : [ r.match(i).group(0) for r in ref_re if r.match(i) ] for i in input }
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much Ivan! You just saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the blank spaces into the regexp. Try this way:

```
ref = ['LYNNDALE\s*(?:RD)?', 'HOMAN\s*(?:AVE)?', 'MAPLEWOOD\s*(?:AVE)?', 'LYNNDALE\s*(?:LN)?']
```